# Getting a id back from a datalist option form using php post.

Tags: php

I am trying to use the datalist feature in html 5 in combination with php. So far it worked well, but i have run into a little problem.

I want my $_POST['select'] to give me back my option id instead of my value (last names), because there could be more of the same last names.

Any tips/hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

My "form":

```
    <form action="index.php?action=listcustomer" method="post" >
      <div class="ui action input">
        <input type="text" name="select" placeholder="Zoek op achternaam"  autocomplete="on" list="datalistcustomer">
         <datalist id="datalistcustomer"> ';
          $sql = databaseConnect()->prepare("SELECT customerID, customerFirstName, customerLastName FROM customers ORDER BY customerLastName ASC");
          $sql->execute();
          $result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            echo '<option id=' .$value['customerID'] .' value=' .$value['customerLastName'] .' label='.$value['customerFirstName'] .' >    </option>';
          }
echo'       </datalist>
          <button type="submit" class="ui blue labeled icon button"> <i    class="user icon"></i> Gaan </button>
      </div>
  </form>
```

My Recieving end:

```
var_dump($_POST['select']);
```

How it looks in my browser:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUCAf.png
It in Dutch so you probably wont understand it. The bigger part is the LastName field (value) and the smaller letters are the First Name (label).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your option tag to look like this:

```
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo '<option id="' .$value['customerID'] . '" value="' .$value['customerID'] . '"' .
         ' label="'.$value['customerFirstName'] .'" >' . $value['customerLastName'] . '</option>';
}
```

Also consider using htmlentities() around dynamic content that you return to the browser as you cannot be sure it does not contain characters which interfere with the html. E.g:

```
htmlentities($value['customerLastName'])
```

Comment: Forget that - totally skipped over the 'Datalist' part and read the code as a 'Select' instead. I would consider using Javascript on submission to replace the value with the customerID.

Comment: Do you have any good site/tutorial where they explain this? I have no Javascript experience.